# HERE Map tile API : decode geometry

Tags: rest, here-api

My purpose is to analyze road geometry. To do that, I use the Map Tile API ([https://vector.hereapi.com/v2/vectortiles/base/mc/11/1100/673/omv?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://vector.hereapi.com/v2/vectortiles/base/mc/11/1100/673/omv?apiKey=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D) for example) to get a binary file. Then I decode the file with the protobuf schema given in HERE documentation to get some JSON data. In this data I find this :

```
"type":2,
"geometry":[
  9,
  1376,
  7552,
  26,
  192,
  207,
  16,
  287,
  111,
  207,
  9,
  0,
  0,
  10,
  239,
  47,
  9,
  0,
  0,
  18,
  239,
  80,
  143,
  336,
  9,
  0,
  0,
  26,
  208,
  288,
  144,
  48,
  176,
  0
]
```

Now I'm looking for a way to decode the geometry part but I have no clue how to do that. In the protobuf schema, the comment attached to the geometry property says :

```
// Contains a stream of commands and parameters (vertices).
// A detailed description on geometry encoding is located in
// section 4.3 of the specification.
```

But I cannot find a way to convert an array of uint32 to a readable stream and I guess I cannot access to the mentioned specification do know how to proceed.

Can I have more details on how the geometry is encoded ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with the following code to decode the data.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(<here-schema>.class, new AdapterTemplate<here-schema>() {
                }).create();


                try {
                    String jsonStr = gson.toJson(<here-schema>.parseFrom(res3));
}
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
}
```